# How to select a file from a input html tag in Selenium 2 gird with a remote driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

How to select a file from a input html tag in Selenium 2 gird with a remote driver?

I am tring to test my webpage and it requires me to select a file.

Here is a HTML snippet:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="csvFile">CSV bestand</label>
  <input type="file" class="form-control" id="csvFile">
</div>
```

And this is a java code snippet:

```
selector = By.cssSelector("input#csvFile");
element = driver.findElement(selector);
element.click();
element.sendKeys("myparcel-adresboek-example.csv");
```

But this no longer seems to work or only for selenium 1

Comment: Can you share the HTML code snippet of it and also your implementation if possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
selector = By.cssSelector("input[type='file']");
element = driver.findElement(selector);
element.sendKeys("complete path of the csv file");
```

No need to click on the element. Because, when you do, it will open a window that is out of the context of browser and can't be handled by selenium.

Comment: This does not seem to fix the problem

Comment: @Funonly: Give the complete path of the csv file in the **sendKeys method**. As I see the path you've given is not complete. For e.g., if a **file "test.csv"**, is in a **folder dir1** in **D drive**, the path to send in the **sendKeys** above will be: **`D:\\dir1\\test.csv`**

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding

```
((RemoteWebDriver) driver).setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
```

line to your code where you have created the driver instance. And thus you don't require to hardcore the file path **(since its not necessary your project is deployed on same path always and in same OS platform)**.
And so in sendkeys

```
element.sendKeys(new File("dir1/test.csv").getAbsolutePath());
```